# Nativescript: getting view of RadListView item

Tags: android, nativescript, nativescript-telerik-ui

Im working on my mobile app, and trying to code it with nativescript,
but Im having a problem I want to animate view of item, in listView ...

Here is my code so far:

```
let page = args.object;
 const radList = page.getViewById('myList');
 const item = radList.getItemAtIndex(0);
 const itemView = radList.getViewForItem(item);
```

But my itemView is always undefined, also I tried with getChildAt() method but it doesnt work...
I dont want to use, itemDeleteAnimation because I want to use my own animation

Comment: Where is this code located?

Comment: its located in listLoaded method, method thats called when list is loaded  <lv:RadListView id="myList" items="{{ items }}" loaded="listLoaded">

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are hitting a timing issue, which can be resolved by using `setTimeout`. Another possibility (if applicable) is to use the `itemLoading` event to get a reference to the view via ListViewEventData

Here is an example of both:

TypeScript

```
export function onRadLoaded(args) {
    const radList = <RadListView>args.object;

    setTimeout(() => {
        const item = radList.getItemAtIndex(0);
        const view = radList.getViewForItem(item);

        console.log(view);
    }, 300);
}

export function onItemLoading(args: ListViewEventData) {
    console.log("args.view: ", args.view);

    console.log("args.data: ", args.data);
    console.log("args.index: ", args.index);
}
```